# Attempting to use symbolic link for var/www/html

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2

this is what I'm trying to accomplish: creating symbolic link from `var/www/html` to a directory in the home (`~`) folder. the directory I'm trying to symlink to in home (`~`) is a git repository, if that makes any difference. I have an index.html file in this directory.

I've created a symbolic link to var/www/html on an Amazon EC2 instance using this command: `ln -s ~/dirIWant/ html`, however this is resulting in the following error when I try to access my webpage: `403 Forbidden "You don't have permission to access / on this server."` I'm using apache.

Has anybody else tried to do something similar and gotten it to work?

Currently, when I go to my website www.blah.com, it shows this 403 error. I've tried to change the permission using `sudo chown -h apache:apache` but it doesn't seem to help. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: The `apache` user (or equivalent) doesn't have read perms to your home dir.  Chmod/chown the target dir to grant permission to the relevant user.  BTW you may find a slightly more telling message in `/var/log/httpd/error_log` or wherever your httpd logs its errors.

Comment: @FrankFarmer when I attempt to switch to apache user using sudo su apache, I get this message: This account is currently not available. Have you experienced this before?

Comment: Yes.  By default, you cannot su apache, as the apache user typically has its shell set to `nologin`.  You can change the user's shell to sh in `/etc/passwd` but this is probably generally a Bad Idea.  Generally, su-ing to apache should not be necessary, especially if you just want to chown.  `sudo chown apache:apache ~/dirIWant/` will suffice in your case, although it'd be wiser to move the directory out of your home dir.

Comment: @FrankFarmer I modified your command to be sudo chown -h apache:apache ~mydir and it works. However, when I go to my website, it still shows the 403 error. Do you have any idea why this is?? Thanks again!

Comment: @FrankFarmer Like I told Dreen below, the directory I'm trying to symlink to in home (~) is a git repository, if that makes any difference in your response to this question...

Comment: You might need to chown the files in the dir as well, e.g. `sudo chown -R apache:apache ~mydir`.  Again, tail your apache `error_log` for further detail.

Comment: @FrankFarmer didn't work either. How do I access the apache error log? it doesn't look like they're in /var/log/httpd/_error_log...sorry for my noobness here.

Comment: your httpd.conf should tell you where your error_log is

Comment: @Derek: In Amazon Linux AMI, Apache logs are by default in `/etc/httpd/logs/`. There may be more than one error log file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because apache runs as *apache* user and the `/var/www/html` is owned by root in Amazon Linux AMI. You can change ownership/permissions as suggested by Frank, or use **userdirs**.

It seems to me that you want the webserver's folder to be conveniently accessible from your home directory (`~`). I wanted something like this on my EC2 and decided to use *Per-user web directories* ([mod_userdir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/public_html.html)).

This feature of lets you keep parts of the HTTP server's space in a directory owned by a user. Each user gets his own directory, located by default in `/home/username/public_html`. The pages, scripts and other files in that directory are accessible to the internet by appending `/~username` to your domain. Additionally, you can change the name of that folder in httpd.conf from `public_html` to something else, like `gitRepo`. In that case, if you have an `index.html` file in `/home/ec2-user/gitRepo/index.html`, it will be accessible to the public via `http://ec2-hostname.aws.amazon.com/~ec2-user/index.html` and be owned by ec2-user, which is convenient for editing files from user level.

To set this up on EC2 (assuming "gitRepo" for the folder name you want to use), use `nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` to open Apache config file and scroll down until you see `<IfModule mod_userdir.c>`. Then change this section to look like the following:

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    #
    # UserDir is disabled by default since it can confirm the presence
    # of a username on the system (depending on home directory
    # permissions).
    #
    UserDir enabled all

    #
    # To enable requests to /~user/ to serve the user's public_html
    # directory, remove the "UserDir disabled" line above, and uncomment
    # the following line instead:
    #
    UserDir gitRepo

</IfModule>
```

Afterwards you should be good to go but ensure the permissions are set up correctly:

```
chmod 711 /home/ec2-user
chmod 755 /home/ec2-user/gitRepo
chown -R ec2-user /home/ec2-user/gitRepo
```

And finally reload the web server like this:

```
sudo service httpd reload
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I asked FrankFarmer, when I attempt to switch users to the apache user so that I can perform sudo chown /myDir, I get the following response: This account is currently not available. Any ideas why?

Comment: Well, you could do a `sudo chown -R ec2-user /var/www/html`, but from your posts it's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish so I'm not sure it will do exactly what you want

Comment: this is what I'm trying to accomplish: creating symbolic link from var/www/html to a directory in the home (~) folder. I have an index.html file in the directory in home (~). Currently, when I go to my website www.blah.com, it shows this 403 error. I've tried to change the permission using sudo chown -h apache:apache but it doesn't seem to help. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: the directory I'm trying to symlink to in home (~) is a git repository, if that makes any difference...

Comment: Have you tried setting up the mod_userdir? You can change from `public_html` to something else, so if your git repo is in `~/gitRepo/` you can use `UserDir gitRepo` in the configuration.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet. Could you explain what mod_userdir is and how that can replace ec2-user? Also, are you saying that in creating public_html this can then link my /var/www/html? Thanks for your help I really appreciate this.

Comment: I have rewritten my answer to hopefully better explain how userdirs can help you.

Comment: this is great. My only question would be is it possible to make it so I can access this index.html page without the index.html appended to the url? for example: http://ec2-hostname.aws.amazon.com/~ec2-user/index.html

Comment: This is a different module, called mod_dir: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html Looking at my ec2's httpd.conf, by default it will show `index.html` or `index.html.var` if they're present in the directory. You can add things like `index.php` if you want those loaded by default too.

Answer (score 0):

```
here how to link file into other directory example with apache2 config file 

**user of symbolic**
## if file available then first remove it 
$ sudo rm -rf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf 
## sudo lm -s  /path of source /path of destination 
$ sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
$ sudo systemctl status apache2

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRSoq.png
```