# I need "/var/www" but Apache2 try to use an empty "/var/www/html"

Tags: apache2, directory

This days I sleep with my `http://localhost`  working, and reading pages from `/var/www`...

I woke up with an  "AH00094" error at Apache2 log, and (Apache2 created?) a surprised `/var/www/html`, that Apache2 try to use.

Now my `http://localhost/anything` not works (error 404 at browser).

**How to fix it?** I need back my `http://localhost` working with files at `/var/www`!

### Context

I am using Ubuntu12 with Apache2, all default and standard.

I checked out error log by `tail /var/log/apache2/error.log` in order to find out exact path that Apache, that shows

```
 ... [core:notice] [pid 1597] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
 ... [:error] [pid 1604] [client 127.0.0.1:40624] script '/var/www/html/info.php' not found or unable to stat
```

The folder  `/var/www/html` is new, all, like '/var/www/info.php', are at `/var/www`, not at `/var/www/html`.

I [fixed the "AH00094" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329323/problem-with-restarting-apache2) editing

```
 sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

and adding at last line

```
 ServerName localhost
```

(now no log errors about localhost, but nothing works)

PS: I checked other related issues, but not is the same problem: [Permissions for /var/www/html](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12414009/287948) , [Attempting to use symbolic link for var/www/html](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11730186/287948)

---

I'm afraid to use the [clues of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891802/how-do-i-change-the-root-directory-of-an-apache-server) ... in my Ubuntu there are no the .conf indicated files. I must create it? Is secure?

---

As @RahilWazir suggested, here is also my  "/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf",

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com
  
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn
  
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  
    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
  </VirtualHost>
  
  # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: Paste the contents of `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` file.

Comment: Thanks @RahilWazir!  well, there are only this other two files, `000-default.conf`  `default-ssl.conf`, can I use `000-default.conf`?

Comment: Yes please show the contents.

Comment: Ops, I edited the questiom, now you can see my 000-default.conf

Comment: There you can see it `DocumentRoot /var/www/html`? Change it to `DocumentRoot /var/www`

Comment: YES!  that was the file, only need to change it... ! Now is working! Thanks a lot!

Comment: A good question: what was happen, what the cause of the change? I do none for change the behaviour of Apache. It can be changed/updated by it self?

Comment: I don't know about the change. But It must be mistakenly changed by someone or by you. Apache always default directory is `/var/www`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See here:

[Why has the apache2 www dir been moved to /var/www/html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21660621/why-has-the-apache2-www-dir-been-moved-to-var-www-html)

The default directory apparently (we were also surprised) moved from `/var/www` to `/var/www/html` for htdocs in Debian, and Ubuntu copied this change. The reasons given are somewhat sound, but the upgrade path is probably “interesting” (as in the Chinese proverb)… as you have encountered.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `/www` as root folder instead of `/www/html` you can simply edit the apache2 config file to have /var/www

Edit 000-default.conf

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

then change

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

to

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
```

Restart apache2 server :

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```