# Use a git repository on /var/www/html/

Tags: linux, git

I am making a web tool and hosting this project on Github. I want to create a repository on my machine (running linux) being able to easily test it on local.

I can test it without problems on /var/www/html (already have apache and php set up), but I am having trouble creating a repository there. However, if I try to create the repo in ~/Documents/Github/PROJECT_NAME it works perfectly; but I can't test my project from there.

**How can I create a repo inside /var/www/html where I can put my project files and run them locally without problems?**

I tried to run `sudo git init` then `sudo git clone git@github.com:xxx/xxx.git` (that is how I clone my repo on ~/Documents/Github/PROJECT_NAME, so I have already exchanged SSH keys with Github) but it didn't work:

> Cloning into 'PrerequisiteVisualizer'...
>
> Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.129' to the list of known hosts.
>
> Permission denied (publickey).
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

**EDIT:** I am able to run without problems

`mkdir ~/Desktop/TESTING
cd ~/Desktop/TESTING
git init
git clone git@github....`

*My question is similar to [Attempting to use symbolic link for var/www/html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730186/attempting-to-use-symbolic-link-for-var-www-html) but it still is different.*

**EDIT2:** I think I need to clarify why the thread I cited isnt what I am looking for. I saw the solution proposed there but note that, as long as I understood the other thread, they created a directory in his home (~) and made it accessible locally using the per-user web directories. But *this is not what I want to do.* I just want to "create a repo inside /var/www/html", not in anywhere else.

Comment: This seems like a basic authentication problem.  It looks like maybe whatever account your using for the `clone` operation doesn't have access to the appropriate private key.

Comment: does git init & git clone work anywhere else, either, with those commands? I don't see anything that would be /var/www specific, just user account specific that stems from using sudo. It seems to be basic issue with setting up ssh agent/ssh key for that account.

Comment: also, why would you first use git init without sudo and then git clone with sudo?

Comment: @eis See my edit. Also, sorry for missing the first sudo, I typed it on the terminal but missed it here.

Comment: @downvoters why downvotting the question? Could you at least post a comment here explaining why is it a bad question? -.-

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The problem isn't strictly with /var/www/html, it's with sudo. If you use sudo to do git, you are running it as a different user, which doesn't have access to your private ssh credentials (nor should it have).

In [the other thread you pointed to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730186/attempting-to-use-symbolic-link-for-var-www-html) there's an explanation of per user www directories, which should be one way of solving your problem. If it doesn't, you could amend the question with reasoning why it doesn't.

---

Update: based on the discussion, you want all content within /var/www/html owned by the user operating git repository. That you should be able to do in the way proposed by @rogerovo in a comment to this answer:

> `sudo chown -R _currentuser_:www-data /var/www/html && chmod -R g+sw /var/www/html`

Comment: this is right. one way to quickfix it `sudo chown -R _currentuser_:www-data /var/www/html && chmod -R g+sw /var/www/html` now it should be possible using `git` without the sudos

Comment: @eis "The problem isn't strictly with /var/www/html, it's with sudo." that might help me. I will check it when I get home. Creating a directory outside /var/www/html and make it accessible locally using the per-user web directories seems to be indeed is one way of solving it. However, I want to just create the repo inside /var/www/html/, which I think it isnt the case in that thread.

Comment: @Xaphanius you still need to think who do you want to own that repo, sudo user or git user? And who do you want to assign the owner of /var/www/html? That needs to be decided first.

Comment: @eis I want the git user to own the repo. But I don't know who should I choose to be the owner of /var/www/html.

Comment: @Xaphanius so where will the repo reside, directly at /var/www/html or /var/www/html/reponame ? Will there be other folders or will the whole site be just about the single repo?

Comment: @eis /var/www/html/reponame. This site will be completely inside the repo; but I might want -in the future- create another site inside /var/www/html/second_repo and so on...

Comment: @Xaphanius would that second_repo be in the owner of the same user still if you choose to do that, or of another user?

Comment: @eis So far I plan for both of them have the same owner.

Comment: @Xaphanius ok. Then I don't think there's a reason not to go with quickfix proposed by rogerovo in the first comment.

Comment: @eis I will try that when I get home. But thanks for helping. :)

Comment: @eis, to avoid problem with permissions in `/var/www/html`, could be a good idea having your git repo in your `home` folder and then creating a symlink in `/var/www/html` which points to your git repo in `home`?

Comment: @floatingpurr I don't see how that changes anything, you would still need to change the ownership/permissions on your git repo files

Comment: What about ownership best practices for /var/www/?

Comment: @YohanW.Dunon that's really a topic that deserves a thread of its own. Here's one such a thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28918996/proper-owner-of-var-www-html

Answer (score 5):

Permissions for /var/www/html folder needs to be changed.
Kindly run this command `sudo chmod  o+w /var/www/html` to give write access to everyone.

Once run, you should be able to transfer files in /var/www/html folder.